# Pandastream video uploading with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pandastream

I'm just in the process of getting video uploading in my app using pandastream, but i can't wrap my head around this attr_accessible rails 3 stuff that isn't in rails 4.
I know it has something to do with strong params, but as to what to pass into the code is confusing me, thanks, here's some snippets.

Here's my video model.

```
    class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :panda_video_id


def panda_video
    @panda_video ||= Panda::Video.find(panda_video_id)
  end
end
```

And Video controller.

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @original_video = @video.panda_video
    @h264_encoding = @original_video.encodings["h264"]
  end

  def new
    @video = Video.new(video_params)
  end

  def create
    @video = Video.create!(params[:video])
    redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @video.id 
  end

  def video_params

    params.require(:video).permit(:panda_video_id, :video)

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I restructured the form to pass the information to the controller in a slightly different way. I was able to set everything up as follows:

VideoController

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @original_video = @video.panda_video
    @h264_encoding = @original_video.encodings["h264"]
  end

  def new
    @video = Video.new
  end

  def create
    @video = Video.create!(video_params)
    redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @video.id
  end

  private
  def video_params
    params.permit(:title, :panda_video_id)
  end
end
```

video/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @video do |f| %>

    <!-- field where the video ID will be stored after the upload -->
    <input id="panda_video_id" type="hidden" name="panda_video_id"/>

    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" name='title' placeholder="Give a title">

    <!-- upload progress bar (optional) -->
    <div class='progress'><span id="progress-bar" class='bar'></span></div>

    <!-- file selector -->
    <div id="browse">Choose file</div>

<% end %>

<script>
    var upl = panda.uploader.init({
        'buttonId': 'browse',
        'progressBarId': 'progress-bar',
        'onQueue': function(files) {
            $.each(files, function(i, file) {
                upl.setPayload(file, {'csrf': "<%= form_authenticity_token %>"});
            })
        },
        'onSuccess': function(file, data) {
            $("#panda_video_id").val(data.id)
        },
        'onComplete': function(){
            $("#new_video").submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```